# Book about TypeScript, RxJS, Web development, NodeJS...

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs

Can anyone suggest me a good book that covers modern techniques in web development?

I know that there is a plenty resources out there, but sometimes is very pleasing and convenient to read it from a hard copy.

I don't need intros, beginnings, overviews... i don't consider myself as beginner :)

Comment: you use linux or windows?

Comment: Thats okay- I asked because some books follow linux some follow windows cmd commands-- so if workstation os is known recommending book becomes easier.

Comment: You can install bash in windows and get linux commands :)

Comment: I know that :) but some are flexible with windows environment only

Comment: nobody is perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

As for TypeScript, there is [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html) by @basarat which I find very useful. :)